# Is SQL Language Based Procedure feature now in Public preview

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This is simple query and would like to know from Snowflake team here , is SQL language  based procedure now available in Snowflake public preview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 2021-07-04 it seems that SQL for stored procedures hasn't been released for public preview yet.

The actual list of preview features could be found at:
**[Preview features](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/release-notes/preview-features.html#features-currently-in-preview)**

I would also recommend to observe **[Release Notes](https://community.snowflake.com/s/topic/0TO0Z000000kHxAWAU/release-notes)** webpage.